# to pass output of a command to a variable in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to pass output of a command to a variable.
Tried many quotes but not successful, please check

I am reading input from a file in $line and processing it, trying to save output in variable a.

```
set a="$($line|cut -d'-' -f 2|cut -d'.' -f 1|sed 's/[^0-9]*//g’)"
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

The first is that you shouldn't be using `set`, that's for shell variables rather than environment variables.

Second, unless `$line` is an actual *command,* you need to echo it.

Third, your closing quote on the `sed` command is the wrong type, `’` instead of `'`.

So, you should be using:

```
a="$(echo $line|cut -d'-' -f 2|cut -d'.' -f 1|sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
```

You can see this in action in the following transcript:

```
pax> line="date=2014.09.05-time=12.34.56"
pax> a="$(echo $line|cut -d'-' -f 2|cut -d'.' -f 1|sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
pax> echo $a
12
```

which grabs the second `-` delimited field (`time=12.34.56`), then the first `.` delimited field from that (`time=12`), then strips off all non-numerics at the start to give just `12`.

Comment: Alternatively, using a here string: `cut -d'-' -f 2 <<<"$line"`.

Comment: What's a shell variable? Anyway, `set a=42` sets `$1` to the literal string `a=42`, which is certainly not what OP wanted but doesn't seem to me to correspond to the explanation of why it "doesn't work"... Also, it probably should be `echo "$line"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `echo`

```
a="$(echo $line|cut -d'-' -f 2|cut -d'.' -f 1|sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$filename` is the name of the file, you're reading from, you're almost there:

```
a="$(<$filename cut -d'-' -f 2|cut -d'.' -f 1|sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
```

The problems are:

- Invocation of `set`, which is not helpful
- Incorrect reading of the file (`$line`) *executes* it, you want to read from it.
- Wrong quote after `//g` - you want a simple single quote (`'`) here

Comment: Thanks for reply!!! But i want to read $filename line by line... This will work for that too...i m yet to try the code

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a long, multi-process pipeline, use the parameter expansion tools provided by the shell itself.

```
tmp1=${line#*-}  # Remove everything up to and include the first -
tmp2=${tmp1%%.*} # Remove everything from the first . onward
a=${tmp2//[!0-9]} # Remove anything that isn't a numerical digit
```

If you are reading from a file, you can fold the first step into the read command itself

```
while IFS=- read first second rest; do
    tmp=${second%%.*}
    a=${tmp//[!0-9]}
done
```

It may also be simpler to define a regular expression to capture the part of the string you want (a sample line would help in defining such a regex).

```
[[ $line =~ $regex ]] && a=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}  # Assuming the first capture group
```